# Spring Roo 1.3.1 ORDER BY code generation bug?

Tags: spring-roo

Roo 1.3.1.RELEASE [rev f4f5256] is generating this incorrect code for ORDER BY:

```
public static List<Company> Company.findAllCompanies(String sortFieldName, String sortOrder) {
    String jpaQuery = "SELECT o FROM Company o";
    if (fieldNames4OrderClauseFilter.contains(sortFieldName)) {
        jpaQuery = jpaQuery + " ORDER BY " + sortFieldName;
        if ("ASC".equalsIgnoreCase(sortOrder) || "DESC".equalsIgnoreCase(sortOrder)) {
            jpaQuery = jpaQuery + " " + sortOrder;
        }
    }
    return entityManager().createQuery(jpaQuery, Company.class).getResultList();
}
```

`sortFieldName` needs an `o.` prepended I'd think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you report it in [Spring Roo JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO)?. I think you're right.

Thank you.

Chema.